# img show half cut on mobile screen but OK on computer screen, css jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Weird thing happen on mobile screen. It is OK on computer screen. when user click the img, it will remove the img, and click another button, it will show the img. See the img, when it show, it's like the first one,half cut,  when I remove, it's like the second one, the pick still there. How can I fix this with css? My code is like below.Appreciate. If I remove the position:fixed for the text below the img, then it is OK, but I need it fixed.

```js
$('#avatar-suggestions-selector').click(function(){
                 $('.avatar').fadeIn();
     $('#img_text').fadeIn();
   });

$('#avatar-suggestions-selector_s').click(function(){
                $('.avatar').fadeOut();
     $('#img_text').fadeOut();
   });
```

```css
 img.avatar{
    display:none;
 position:fixed ;
    top: 61px ;
    left: 12px ;
 width:140px;
 
}
#img_text{
 display:none;
 position: fixed;
 left: 25px;
 background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #6d9bff;
 top: 218px;
 color: white;
 padding: 8px;
 border-radius: 9px;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
       img.avatar{
          width: 100%;
       }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 420px){
       img.avatar{
          width: 100%;
       }
    }
```

I hope this helps. Just put this in your CSS. For Tablet your can use the 768 viewport and for mobiles you can use the 420 viewport.

Comment: Thanks for you time. it doesn't work. I found out that If I remove the position:fixed for the text below the img, then it is OK, but I need it to be fixed, so what can I do?

Comment: Can you provide some fiddle for this ? So that I could be more specific on what your needing.

Comment: Thanks, I wish I can, I use child theme, so it has too much code to paste. I have tried to simplify everything. I found out the problem it is the fixed position, remove the it, then it is OK, but what kind of css code that I need to add if I need it to be fixed?